# Integral using Parseval's Theorem

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

How would I integrate 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}(x)}{x^{2}}\,dx$$  using Fourier Transform methods, i.e. using Parseval's Theorem ?

How would I then use that to calculate: 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^{4}(x)}{x^{4}}\,dx$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parseval in this case states that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) g^*(x) = \frac1{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, F(k) G^*(k) $$

where $F$ and $G$ are the respective FTs of $f$ and $g$.  (Integrability conditions such as absolute integrability over the real line must be satisfied for both pairs of functions.)

When $f(x) = g(x) = \sin{x}/x$, then $F(k) = G(k) = \pi I_{[-1,1]}$ and we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2} = \frac1{2 \pi} \pi^2 \int_{-1}^1 dk  = \pi$$

When $f(x) = g(x) = \sin^2{x}/x^2$, then $F(k) = G(k) = \pi (1-|k|/2) I_{[-2,2]} $, and we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{\sin^4{x}}{x^4} = \frac1{2 \pi} \pi^2 \int_{-2}^2 dk \left ( 1-\frac{|k|}{2} \right )^2 = \frac{2 \pi}{3}$$

Comment: How did you get F(k)=G(k) to be πI[−1,1] in the first case and a similar expression in the second case? I guess that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: The first case is a very well-known result, one of the first taught to students learning Fourier transforms.  Certainly taught before applying Parseval's theorem to integrals.  The second case may be derived from the first by, e.g., the convolution theorem.  You may check both results by Foureir transforming $F(k)$ back to $f(x)$.

Comment: The function $x \mapsto { \sin x \over x}$ is **not** absolutely integrable.

Answer (score 3):

Both integrals can be computed through integration by parts, since:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}\,dx = \pi$$
and: 
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin^4 x}{x^4}\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(2x)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(4x)}{3x^3}\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\cos(2x)-\cos(4x)}{3x^2}\,dx=\frac{2\pi}{3}.$$
The general integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^n\,dx $$
can be computed from the pdf of the [Irwin-Hall distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution).